# How can I parse square bracketed string to std::vector?

Tags: c++, parsing, vector

I'm trying to parse square bracketed string (with delimiter ',') (ex, `[1,2,3]`, or `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`) to vector.

Expected results to these examples are `std::vector<int>{1,2,3}` and `std::vector<std::vector<int>> {std::vector<int> {1,2,3}, std::vector<int> {4,5,6}}`, respectively.

I want to implement this using some generic code, but it fails at compilation.

What I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename Test, template<typename...> class Ref>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class Ref, typename... Args>
struct is_specialization<Ref<Args...>, Ref> : std::true_type {};


template<typename T, typename UnaryOperation>
std::enable_if_t<is_specialization<T, std::vector>::value, T> parse1D(std::string a, UnaryOperation unary_op) { // If Base(1D) Case, just split and type-cast.
    T ans;
    if (a.length() < 2 || a[0] != '[' || a[a.length() - 1] != ']') return ans; // Error Case

    std::regex re(",");
    std::sregex_token_iterator it(a.begin()+1, a.end()-1, re, -1), end;
    std::transform(it, end, std::back_inserter(ans), unary_op);
    return ans;
}

template<typename T, typename UnaryOperation>
std::enable_if_t<is_specialization<T,std::vector>::value, T> parse(std::string a, UnaryOperation unary_op) {
    T ans;
    if (a.length() < 2 || a[0] != '[' || a[a.length() - 1] != ']') return ans; // Error Case

    if (is_specialization<T::value_type, std::vector>::value) { // recursive case
        // some recursive code with parse function
        return ans;
    }else { // base case (1D vector)
        return parse1D<T>(a, unary_op);
    }
}
```

When I call parse function with

```
auto ret = parse<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>(std::string("[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]"), [](const auto& el) {
    return std::stoi(el);
});
```

, it produces the error "There is no = operator that receives int type as RHS" at std::transform function.

I understood this error as,
although type T is `vector<vector<int>>`, so it should go to recursive case, the compiler tries to compile the `else` case, which calls `parse1D`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Compiler cannot know which path will `if` take so it must instantiate both branches. Use `constexpr if` instead.

Comment: Quimby is right. However you're attempting to use SFINAE here, instead of C++17's `if constexpr`. You're doing it incorrectly though: Since `parse` is only available for types where `is_specialization<T>` derives from `std::true_type`, the condition in the `if` is always `true`; the whole if-else should be replaced with `/* some recursive code with parse function */ return ans;` for this reason. The overload for the 1D case should have the same signature (and  function name) as `parse` except for the return type being `std::enable_if_t<!is_specialization<T,std::vector>::value, T>`

Comment: Checking for a specialization of vector is too limiting. Your SFINAE should test `operator[]` directly.